# submodule is archived on gitlab

Tags: git, git-submodules, sendinblue

I have installing Sendinblue api with following this link [SendinBlue's API v3 Php Library](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library) on my local, and I made some modification on this api. I can see that I have a submodule on this api.

When I push it to my repository on gitLab, the submodule is archived and I can't see the content of this folder: `vendor/sendinblue/api-v3-sdk`.

This is the api Architecture :

[image: api Architecture]

And this what I see in gitlab:

[image: Git lab]

`$ ls -la` display display this:
[image]

Comment: This is how submodules work. They are just a pointer, not the actual contents of the repository. There's no "archive"; this is just how GitLab displays a submodule.

Comment: but when my colleague clone this project, this folder is empty on local

Comment: Your colleague needs to initialize their Git submodules after cloning. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#_cloning_submodules

Comment: I follow your link but when I use this command `$ls -la ` I can't see .gitmodules

Comment: You have to show us your repository or at least the commands you've used to add the submodule. Did you add and commit file `.gitmodules`?

Comment: I update my question to show you the result of `ls -la`command